# I couldn't use mongod in the new M1 macbook, where each time I wrote it there are a bunch of codes appear in the terminal. What is the solution?

Tags: mongodb, terminal, nosql, macos-big-sur, mongodb-shell

I have watched several videos on Youtube about this issue and none of them have worked. I know that I could not create mkdir -p /data/db because it will show me read-only due to Apple's system updates.
You will find below what the terminal shows to me when I try to run a local server by using mongod. In the other hand, I can use mongo command and it works fine.

[click here to see an image for the codes that appears when I use the mongod command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcWob.jpg)

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing that image.  In general, the first log line with 'E' tells you what's wrong

Comment: "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Error setting up listener","attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Address already in use"}}} that what it said.

Comment: And there it is: "Address already in use"

Comment: "Address already in use" means the IP:port that it is trying to bind to is already in use by something else

Comment: So, what can I do?

Comment: figure out what that something else is

Comment: Is there a specific code that may help me to figure it out?

Comment: I have used sudo killall mongod. Then I wrote mongod command another timed where this message appear      "s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found. Create the missing directory or specify another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option, or (2) by adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file."}}